# How to find the id of the active Select2 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a form with multiple select menus generated with Select2 (version 4) where the id value of each select element is set dynamically. I'd like to find the id of the select element the user clicks on.

I can get this to work

```
$('.js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data').on('select2:open', function (evt) {
        myValue = $(this).attr('id');
 });
```

But I need to use `myValue` as a parameter for `data` inside an ajax call so an option getting the id of the active select2 element is needed. I've seen posts that suggest `var selectedEle = $(document.activeElement)` but I don't know how to get the id from there.

**UPDATE**

It seems I can include this as the value for the data parameter

```
data: getSelectedElement(function() {
            return JSON.stringify({variable: myValue})
        }),
```

with the function as

```
function getSelectedElement(callback) {
        $('.js-example-tokenizer-ajax-data').on('select2:opening', function (evt) {
            myValue = $(this).attr('id');
            callback();
        });
    }
```

But there are still some timing issues since the ajax seems to fire before a select element is clicked since when I load the page I get an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` I gather since there was no value for myValue when the page loaded.

Are there other options to get the id of the selected select2 element? Alternatively, are there ways to sort out the timing issue?

Comment: What event triggers the ajax call? Is it clicking the select element?

Comment: Yes, but with Select2 I don't know how to get the id from the click event.

Comment: Updated with a guess, but that's all I can give you without being able to see the html structure or the `.select2` or even the `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

If `var selectedEle = $(document.activeElement)` does in fact get the element that you want you can simply do `document.activeElement.id`.

## Update based on poster's update:

In a different stack overflow answer someone said `this.context` will give you the correct element, in which case `this.context.id` would give you the id.

Comment: I'm not getting any value from `document.activeElement.id`

Comment: Did you log document.activeElement to make sure it is getting the element you want? Remember, that is the prerequisite for `.id` to work.

Comment: Yes, I just get `<input class=​"select2-search__field" type=​"search" tabindex=​"0" autocomplete=​"off" autocorrect=​"off" autocapitalize=​"off" spellcheck=​"false" role=​"textbox" aria-autocomplete=​"list" placeholder style=​"width:​ 0.75em;​">`​

Comment: That element does not have an id, so I don't think it's the one you want. Without seeing your HTML it's hard to know.